# ioctl call flow in linux kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the call flow of the ioctl call in linux kernel and I have a question - when we call ioctl from userspace, which function or module in linux kernel is responsible to convert this ioctl call to the corresponding ioctl call in the driver. I know that the ioctl for the driver will not be called directly from userspace. First the call has to go through some kernel API, and that API will in turn invoke the driver ioctl. Please help me point out that kernel API which transfers ioctl to the suitable driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we find a `struct file` from a path on `open` call [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L1105) or more like [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L3592).

Then the file descriptor is translated from a number to `struct file` [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/file.c#L750) and [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/file.c#L716).

Then you just call `ioctl` from `file_operations` like [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ioctl.c#L41) but the whole [ioctl.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ioctl.c) I guess should be worth a loop.